# 'slider' is possibly 'null'

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I have no clue how to fix it, I am pretty sure it's something easy but I can't figure it out..

here's the line of code that is generating the error from TS:

```
    const slideLeft = () => {
      const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
      slider.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft - 1000;
  };

  const slideRight = () => {
    const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    slider.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft + 1000;
  };
```

The ID slider is causing the error ('slider' is possibly 'null')

```
      <div
        id="slider"
        className="flex items-center w-full h-full overflow-x-scroll scroll whitespace-nowrap scroll-smooth scrollbar-hide"
      >
```

Any pointers or tips is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the value returned from [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is either an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) or `null` if no element matching the specified ID was found.

There are a couple of optoins you can use to mitigate a `null` value.

Perform an explicit `null` check.

```
const slideLeft = () => {
    const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    if (slider == null) return;
    slider.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft - 1000;
};
```

Use the [`non-null and non-undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-and-non-undefined-type-guards) assertion operator.

```
const slideRight = () => {
    const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    slider!.scrollLeft = slider!.scrollLeft + 1000;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `document.getElementById` method has a return type of `HTMLElement | null`. If no element with the provided `id` exists in the DOM, the method returns a `null` value.

To solve your problem, just check if `slider` contains a value:

```
const slideLeft = () => {
  const slider = document.getElementById("slider");

  if(slider) {
    slider!.scrollLeft = slider!.scrollLeft - 1000;
  }
};
```